# Getting Windows error 32 process can not access file it is used by another process

Tags: python

I download podcasts that have really long file names and I'm stripping them so that they just have the city name, date and hour (meaning first, second or third hour). It all seems to work except for os.rename(file, new_name), where it tells me that Windows can't access the file.

```
import re, os, glob
from ID3 import *

for files in glob.glob("f:\\Download\*podcasts*"):
  os.chdir(files)
  for file in os.listdir("."):
   if re.search("\A[1-3].",file):  # original filenames begin with 1.,2. or 3.
      tags=ID3(file)
      date = re.search("\w*.-\w*.-\w*.",file) # filenames contain date in MMM-DD-YYYY
      date_clean = date.group(0).strip()
      hour = re.search("hr\d", file)  # file names also contain hr. 1,2 or 3 at end
      hour_clean = hour.group(0).strip()
      tags['ARTIST'] = "Portland Podcast"
      tags['TITLE'] = date_clean + hour_clean
      new_name = "Portland-" + date_clean + "-" + hour_clean +".mp3"
      print "Changing",file,"to",new_name+"."
      os.rename(file,new_name)               
  os.chdir("F:\\Download")                           
  os.getcwd()                                        
  os.system("pause")
```

Comment: “It all seems to work” - you mean the rest of your code?

Comment: What is unclear about the error message? If the file is used by another process, exit that other program. Did you try a reboot to make sure none accesses it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is holding a reference to the file you try to move. Place a `try/except` block around the `shutil.rename` and print out which file causes the problem. When you find out which file causes the problem find out who is holding a reference to it.

One way to find who is holding a reference to a file is either using [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) or [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/)

*Update:*

I took a look at the code of the ID3 library and it seems that, if you pass in a filename, it doesn't close the file, EVER :D

You should do something like:

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    tags = ID3(f)
    # do your stuff
shutil.rename(filename, ...)
```

Comment: I think it's happening because I'm looping through the directories. Viktor, I added a try and exception block but I just get the same error; Windows 32 error, file is already in use.

Comment: But have you found out which application holds the reference to file that cannot be deleted?

Comment: I found out what the problem was. The ID3 tag function keeps the file open so it can't be renamed. Once I took that out, the loop completes. With that in, it keeps the file open since it's editing the ID3 tags. Now I know why it worked before - I used mutagen before (I think).

Comment: Never mind, saw the check mark. Dang, I can be dense sometimes!

Comment: One last note; ID3 was made in like 2002 and it sucks, so I switched to eyed3 which makes you open the file, create tags, then close file. Works great.